# why assuming $p$ does not divide $b_0$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Here is the proof I am reading from John Beachy, fourth edition:

[image]

I do not understand why assuming $p$ does not divide $b_0$? Is this by the opposite of Euclid's Lemma or what?

Can anyone explain this to me please?

Comment: By the linked *divisibility product rule* if $p$ divides both $a_0$ and $b_0$ then $ p^2\mid a_0 b_0,\,$ contra hypothesis, hence at least one of $a_0$ or $b_0$ is not divisible by $p.\ \ $

Comment: The theroem hypotheses states that $p^2\not \mid a_0$.  As $a_0=b_0c_0$ and $p^2\not \mid a_0=b_0c_0$ we can not have $p$ dividing *BOTH* $b_0$ and $c_0$.  (That would mean $p^2|a_0$.)  So $p$ must not divide one $c_0$ or $b_0$.  It could divide $b_0$ but then it wouldn't divide $c_0$. Or it could divide $c_0$ but then it wouldn't divide $b_0$. Or $p$ could divide neither.  But since at least one can't be divide and as these are just labels.  WOLOG we call the one that is not divisible by $p$, we call it $b_0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the preceding discussion, that $p^2$ does not divide $a_0 = b_0 c_0$.  So it cannot be the case that $p$ divides both $b_0$ and $c_0$.

But the roles of $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ are interchangeable, and hence so are $b_0$ and $c_0$.  Thus without loss of generality one may assume $p$ does not divide $b_0$.

Comment: @Brain In other words, since we know that $p$ doesn't divide *one* of the constant terms, we simply choose to label that constant term (the one that $p$ doesn't divide) as $b_0$.  We can do that because, as stated in the answer above, the roles of $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ are completely interchangeable.

Comment: but in order to divide $a_0,$ p needs to divide only one of $b_0$ or $c_0$ not both, right? I do not understand the logic from the beginning @RobertShore

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).
It's best for site health to delete this answer (which also minimizes community time wasted on dupe processing.)

Comment: We are told from the very beginning that $p^2\not \mid a_0=b_0c_0$. That means we can't have $p$ dividing *both*.  So at *most* $p$ can (but doesn't have to) divide one, but it absolutely can't divide both.  So at most it divides one (or none).  And the one that *isn't* divisible by $p$ we call $b_0$.

Comment: @fleablood  ok I see

Comment: @fleablood:  Note that $p | a_0$ is part of the setup for Eisenstein's criterion, so indeed $p$ divides one of the two constant terms $b_0,c_0$ (just not both of them).

Comment: Oh, oops.  I wasn't really reading the details.